# Howto disable Price per Customer group?

Tags: price, index, customer-group

does anyone know if there is a simple way or extension to disable price indexer per customer group?

i have over 1000 Customer groups and over 100k products in catalog. So the price indexer raises extremly in numbers.

I don't need the feature to have different prices for each customer group.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

These extensions may address your issue.
http://vovsky.net/index.php/extensions/magento-customer-price-extension.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-prices.html

And also this thread will be helpful. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/23057/P30/

Comment: My Question was how to disable the price per customergroup feature in Magento. We use EE 13.1.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the question